# How to achieve layout for given screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I tried a lot of things from `Framelayout`, `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` but not getting any idea how to achieve the following screen layout in Android.

So, Let's break into `LinearLayout`.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

- First section is `TextView` where we can see `Manhattan, NY`
- Second section is `ImageView` where we can see hearts and amount.
- Third section is different background color with two profile picture including text.
- Fourth Section is Simply text with `Drable` line.
- Fifth section is very similar to fourth section
- Sixth section is a button

I am able to get first two section using `LinearLayout` and `Bitmap` to add heart shape image.

## Question

How to achieve `Third section`? Do I need `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`?

What I am getting is the third section is a `placeholder` where we set a background color and add two Images. right?

What would be the best to achieve the whole layout?

Comment: I didn't get any point for negative vote?

Comment: You could set the gray background for the entire linear layout.  Then for the third section do a linear layout with the two images.

For the other individual sections you do a white background color, which will override the gray that is set for the entire layout.

Comment: What if we I have dynamic count of Images in third section? Do I need to add `FrameLayout` in this section? Because that would be a slider section

Comment: Def you are correct, I was wrong.  For the third section use a FrameLayout.   The type of FrameLayout you want to use is horizontalScrollView.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

You need [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), the most flexible one -- you can do only section 3 with it and nest it into a `LinearLayout` or do the whole layout with a single `RelativeLayout` (although the latter option is not very good for dividing available space proportionally, that you easily get using `LinearLayout` with weights)

Comment: So, you are suggesting to us `RelativeLayout` for section 3 I need to nest `Horizontal Linear layout` in `RelativeLayout` . right?

Comment: No, not really, I meant nest the `RelativeLayout` of section 3 into the outer `LinearLayout`, the one you already have, no need for additional wrapping -- as opposed to possibly ditching the outer `LinearLayout` and doing the whole screen in a single `RelativeLayout` -- I just said that's also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Ivan's answer, for Android XML you have to do something similar to table based design.

You can use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html as a reference to everything you're allowed to do with RelativeLayout and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html as a reference for what you can do with LinearLayout.

But generally

- If you want elements to be placed vertically or horizontally next to each other, so that each takes up a certain amount of space, you use a LinearLayout. The following example would create a row of three text views horizontally, each taking up 1/3 of the screen. Note that your weights do NOT have to add up to 1.0 exactly.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

- If you want an element on top of another element, or adjacent to another element, use RelativeLayout. The following code will create a big ImageButton, put a translucent text label on the bottom of the image, and put a caption beneath the image

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/example.png"
    android:id="@+id/exampleImage"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/exampleImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/exampleImage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/exampleImage"
    android:background="#80808080"
    android:text="on image label"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/exampleImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/exampleImage"
    android:layout_below="@id/exampleImage"
    android:background="#FF808080"
    android:text="below image caption"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```